# Find distortion coefficients from known pixel coordinates and real world coordinates

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I have been searching for days after a possible (alternative) solution to determine a camera's distortion coefficients WITHOUT the use chessboards/checkerboard. The reason for this is that I have sufficiently many points for which I know both the real-world position and the 2D-image position and I image it could be done using this information.

So, here is what I know about:

**Camera**

```
focal_length  = 3.9
image_height  = 3456 
image_width   = 4608
esl_height    = 35  
sensor_height = 4.69
sensor_width  = 6.26
pixel_size    = 1.34/1000
FOV_x         = 71.9
FOV_y         = 56.7

F_x = image_width /(2 * tan(FOV_x* pi / 360))
F_y = image_height /(2 * tan(FOV_y* pi / 360))

C_x = image_width / 2
C_y = image_height / 2

row1 = [F_x,0,C_x]
row2 = [0,F_y, C_y]
row3 = [0,0,1]


camera_matrix = np.matrix([row1,row2,row3])
```

which gives:

```
matrix([[3.17701054e+03, 0.00000000e+00, 2.30400000e+03],
        [0.00000000e+00, 3.20254589e+03, 1.72800000e+03],
        [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00]])
```

**Data**

I have a dataset containing 49 points for which I have both the real-world (x,y) positions (I also have the z values, but I am really only interested in the (x,y) position. Also, I have the pixel positions for all these points in an image (They are the bounding box centers in the object deterction I perform.

```
  id  manual.location.x  manual.location.y  manual.location.z  \
0    0            32.9878            41.9033              0.215   
1    1            32.9878            44.4404              0.215   
2    2            32.9878            44.4404              0.215   
3    3            32.9878            44.4404              0.565   
4    4            32.9878            44.4404              0.565   
5    5            32.9878            44.4404              0.565   
6    6            32.9878            44.4404              0.565   
7    7            32.9878            44.4404              0.565   
8    8            32.9878            41.9033              0.753   
9    9            32.9878            44.4404              0.779   
10  10            32.9878            44.4404              0.779   
11  11            32.9878            44.4404              0.779   
12  12            32.9878            41.9033              1.024   
13  13            32.9878            44.4404              1.024   
14  14            32.9878            42.7490              1.100   
15  15            32.9878            43.5947              1.100   
16  16            32.9878            43.5947              1.100   
17  17            32.9878            43.5947              1.100   
18  18            32.9878            43.5947              1.100   
19  19            32.9878            44.4404              1.231   
20  20            32.9878            44.4404              1.231   
21  21            32.9878            44.4404              1.231   
22  22            32.9878            44.4404              1.231   
23  23            32.9878            42.7490              1.320   
24  24            32.9878            43.5947              1.412   
25  25            32.9878            42.7490              1.412   
26  26            32.9878            43.5947              1.412   
27  27            32.9878            44.4404              1.412   
28  28            32.9878            44.4404              1.458   
29  29            32.9878            44.4404              1.458   
30  30            32.9878            44.4404              1.458   
31  31            32.9878            44.4404              1.458   
32  32            32.9878            42.7490              1.620   
33  33            32.9878            42.7490              1.620   
34  34            32.9878            43.5947              1.620   
35  35            32.9878            43.5947              1.620   
36  36            32.9878            42.7490              1.620   
37  37            32.9878            44.4404              1.651   
38  38            32.9878            44.4404              1.651   
39  39            32.9878            44.4404              1.651   
40  40            32.9878            44.4404              1.651   
41  41            32.9878            44.4404              1.651   
42  42            32.9878            42.7490              1.850   
43  43            32.9878            42.7490                NaN   
44  44            32.9878            44.4404                NaN   
45  45            32.9878            44.4404                NaN   
46  46            32.9878            44.4404              1.850   
47  47            32.9878            43.5947              1.850   
48  48            32.9878            44.4404              1.850   

    bbox_center_x  bbox_center_y  
0          4269.5         2914.0  
1          1035.0         2883.5  
2           843.5         2880.0  
3          1516.5         2529.0  
4          1247.5         2527.0  
5          1730.0         2525.5  
6           987.0         2522.0  
7           765.5         2520.0  
8          4435.0         2356.5  
9          1196.0         2257.0  
10          938.5         2255.0  
11          704.5         2250.0  
12         4547.0         1998.0  
13         1291.0         1980.0  
14         3681.0         1864.5  
15         2394.0         1856.0  
16         1931.5         1854.0  
17         2043.0         1853.5  
18         2043.0         1853.5  
19         1620.0         1676.0  
20         1267.0         1675.5  
21          847.0         1672.5  
22          593.5         1669.5  
23         3783.5         1452.0  
24         1931.5         1446.5  
25         3346.5         1443.5  
26         2878.0         1443.0  
27         1632.0         1350.0  
28         1409.0         1346.5  
29          945.0         1339.5  
30          727.0         1334.0  
31          534.5         1332.0  
32         4349.0         1109.0  
33         3859.0         1101.0  
34         1920.5         1097.5  
35         2878.0         1090.5  
36         3364.0         1087.0  
37         1460.5         1037.0  
38         1290.5         1036.0  
39         1065.5         1034.0  
40          748.0         1032.5  
41          473.0         1029.0  
42         4262.0          726.0  
43         3683.5          713.0  
44         1375.0          710.0  
45         1094.5          708.0  
46          850.0          705.0  
47         3103.5          702.5  
48          375.5          701.5
```

**Pixel to real world without distortion taken into account**

I have managed to get the real world positions from the pixels, but as you can imagine, the farther away I am from the image center `(C_x, C_y)` the farther the result of the transformation is. I assume it is due to distortion. So, what I do is this:

I define four points in a quadrilater in my image and their real-world counterparts

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import scipy

coords = {
    "realworld": np.array([
        [32.9878,41.9033], 
        [32.9878,44.4404], 
        [32.9878,42.7490], 
        [32.9878,44.4404] 
    ]),
    "pixel": np.array([
        [4269.5,2914.0], 
        [843.5,2880.0], 
        [4262.0,726.0], 
        [375.5,701.5] # 
    ])
}


realworld_array = coords['realworld']
pixel_array= coords['pixel']
```

and find the `Perspective Transform` using `opencv`:

```
M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(np.float32(pixel_array),np.float32(realworld_array))
```

I define my function from pixels to real-world points

```
def R2_to_R3(pixel):
    
    if type(pixel) != np.ndarray:
        pixel = np.array(pixel).reshape(1,2)
    assert pixel.shape[1]==2, "Need (N,2) input array" 
    pixel = np.concatenate([pixel, np.ones((pixel.shape[0],1))], axis=1)
    lonlat = np.dot(M,pixel.T)
        
    return (lonlat[:2,:]/lonlat[2,:]).T
```

Now, for the center of the image:

```
pixel = (C_x,C_y)=(2304.0, 1728.0)
R2_to_R3((C_x,C_y))
array([[32.98780048, 43.50150617]])

Real world coordinates [32.98780048, 43.5314615]
```

But for a point further away

```
pixel = (4435.0,2356.5)
R2_to_R3(pixel)
array([[32.98780025, 42.11436824]])

Real world coordinates: [32.98780025, 41.9033]
```

which is rather bad.

Now, note that I never use my camera matrix and this is due to the fact that I do not know how to compute the distortion coefficient. Is there a way to do this without the painful process of doing the chessboard exercice?

Grateful for anything that would improve my work.

**Update**

After some searching (i.e. googling), I found that this could be achieved using `cv.calibrateCamera()` in the following way:

```
image_height  = 3456 
image_width   = 4608
w = image_width
h = image_height
rvec = (0, 0, 0)  # rotation relative to the frame: Static
tvec = (0, 0, 0)  # translation relative to the frame: Static
size = (w,h)

cv.calibrateCamera(
[pts3d], [pts2d],
size,camera_matrix,np.float32([0,0,0,0,0]),
flags=0
| cv.CALIB_FIX_K1
| cv.CALIB_FIX_K2
| cv.CALIB_FIX_K3
| cv.CALIB_FIX_K4
| cv.CALIB_FIX_K5
,rvec,tvec)
```

However, this returns:

```
File "<ipython-input-319-af5936255ea4>", line 31
    ,rvec,tvec)
              ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

What does this mean?